# New Tab Navigation is Sometimes Not Loading the Page, Why?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

My Java Selenium WebDriver script clicks a link in a web page that opens a new tab and navigates to an external site. There are multiple of these links to different social media.

The problem I have is that sometimes the new tab opens and tries to load the external page but stops all together.

I figured this isn't a big deal, I will just refresh the page with my code like I would manually in the browser and it will attempt to reload the page. I was wrong.

Evidently, perhaps in Chrome only, the reload/refresh functionality included with Selenium and even JavaScript does not work the same as clicking the refresh button. In this circumstance, they do nothing at all.

Luckily, this only happens every now and then but it does cause my test to fail when it does happen.

When this happens, the title area of the tab says "untitled", the page is blank white with nothing on it, and the desired URL will be in the address bar. Only manually clicking the refresh button will reload the page properly.

I haven't seen this happen in Firefox even once so I am going to assume it is only an issue in Chrome.

Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Here is what I have tried in JavaScript:

```
document.location.reload(false);

document.location.reload(true);
```

I tried these in Java Selenium:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();

public Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F5).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

I should also say that these refresh methods work normally when the page is working normally. It is literally this one situation where they do not and I don't know what to do. Is there no way to programmatically click the refresh button in the browser? I need to find out if I can move the mouse and have it click.

Answer (score 0):

Might be chrome web driver issue. try updating to latest.

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");

    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0)); // switch back to main screen        
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com");
```

Comment: Everything is up to date. Your fifth line of code is giving me an idea to try sending ctrl+f5. I would like to do this with JavaScript instead of Java. I will give it a shot and let you know how it goes.